# RedirectView to external site. How to append parameters?

Tags: django, django-urls

I would like to redirect from my page to external site. This external site address is defined and never changes... And I can implement it... The challenge comes from:

I have a form, which posts Q into my view function, which gives final string of parameters to pass into the pattern of url supposedly attached to the main address of this external web site after the ? mark... I just cannot find the information how to pass and attach this string to a given url. Somehow it's difficult for me, please don't judge too harsh. Parameter is only one, it is a string, which formed in view function.

I use RedirectView in urls.py:

```
path('do_request/found/', RedirectView.as_view(url='https://docs.djangoproject.com/'), name='found_objects'),
```

In views.py (there are probably some mistakes, but it's just for the purpose of the question):

```
class UserFoundRequestView(TemplateView):
    model=ForQuery
    template_name='found_objects.html'

    def get_results(self, request):
        our_queries = ForQuery.objects.all()
        query=self.request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            our_object=ForQuery.objects.filter(query_id__iexact=query)
        for x in our_queries:
            if x.query_id == our_object.query_id:
                name = x.dep_station
        #context = {
        #   'name' : name,
        #}
        return name

    def get_string(request):
        base_url = 'https://docs.djangoproject.com/'
        query_name = get_results()
        query_string = urlencode(query_name)
        url = '{}?{}'.format(base_url, query_string)
        return redirect(url)
```

Either to append to url or just bring formed url to patterns->path...

Thank you for the help!

my template:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    <p>Paste value to the field</p>
    <form method="get" action="{% url 'found_objects' %}">
        <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="search by value" class="m-1 p-1"><button class=" btn btn-outline-primary m-1 p-1" type="Submit">Search</button>    
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Just to be clear. I want to attach a formed string (essentially parameters, formed in view function) after the ? mark, to the address of the external web page. I use RedirectView.as_view for this purpose.

Comment: If somebody knows where to read about this topic, the advise would be nice... I just looked through this topic whole day and cannot find anything helpful for me... Most of the links are talking about internal site urls, and I found one helpful link, but mostly it's talking about internal links and gives one example with on the surface for my topic. So I generally understand this idea, but don't have success implementing it in exact manner. Thank you. If somebody wants to make a tutorial on this topic, that's a great idea to do it!

Comment: I am not sure what the exact issue is with your view, but a simple string concatenation should be sufficient: url = base_url + '?' + query_string

Comment: I'm confused how to bring this url into the url path...

Comment: You don't. On Form submit the view function is triggered (this is the url -> view mapping). The view function then returns the redirect. See the doc for redirect shortcut function: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/

Comment: Please let me think about the comment... Meanwhile somehow I have this fault at this time: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/sc_site/do_request/found/url

Comment: I changed my path a bit:path('do_request/found/', RedirectView.as_view(url='url'), name='found_objects'),

Comment: can you please post your form / template

Comment: I just did... Thank you for the help and link... Being reading and writing the code different ways for past 10 hours... Don't want to leave the topic without resolving the issue.And I try to post topics to StackOverflow, when I start really struggling...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216440/discussion-between-jonas-and-bugthefifth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to trigger the view by submitting the form and the view itself will return the according redirect. Between is the url mapping that links the form submit to the according view like so:

**urls.py**

```
from your_app.views import redirect_view

path('do_request/found/', redirect_view, name='found_objects'),
```

**views.py**

```
def redirect_view(request):

        our_queries = ForQuery.objects.all()
        query = request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            our_object=ForQuery.objects.filter(query_id__iexact=query)
        for x in our_queries:
            if x.query_id == our_object.query_id:
                name = x.dep_station

        base_url = 'https://docs.djangoproject.com/'
        query_string = urlencode(name)
        url = '{}?{}'.format(base_url, query_string)
        return redirect(url)
```